# Dropdown box in Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, el

I have a select box something like the following in Spring.

```
<form:select path="cmbZone" multiple="false" class="validate[required] text-input tooltip" title="Mandatory select field.">
    <form:option value="">Select</form:option>

    <c:forEach items="${zoneList}" var="row">
        <form:option value="${row[0]}">${fn:escapeXml(row[1])}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

This uses a JSTL `forEach` loop to iterate over a list of items. `zoneList` is a list containing an array of `Object`s like `List<Object[]>` retrieved from a database using HQL like the following.

```
List<Object[]>zoneList=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select z.zoneId, z.zone from Zone z order by z.zoneId").list();
```

I want to achieve the same using `<form:options>`. How could I specify the `itemLabel` and the `itemValue` properties of `<form:options>`?

```
<form:select path="cmbZone" multiple="false" class="validate[required] text-input tooltip" title="Mandatory select field.">
    <form:option value="">Select</form:option>
    <form:options items="${zoneList}"/>
</form:select>
```

What would be `itemLabel` and `itemValue` in this?

```
<form:options items="${zoneList}" itemLabel="" itemValue=""/>
```

I'm using Spring 3.2.0. I was referring to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/) blog but couldn't find the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Hibernate query to

```
List<Zone> zoneList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
    "select z from Zone z order by z.zoneId").list();
```

Now that you have objects with properties, you can use

```
<form:options items="${zoneList}" itemLabel="zone" itemValue="zoneId"/>
```

Comment: So, we don't have selected fields in this regards? The `Zone` table in the database have other fields also including `zone` and `zoneId` which are unnecessary to retrieve here. Is it not possible to achieve the same with selected fields only?

Comment: If it fits in a select box, loading all the fields vs. loading only two will probably make a negligible difference (if any). But you could also create a LightZone object, with only two fields, and create an instance of LightZone for every row retrieved from your original query.

Comment: That's done but is it really not possible with `List<Object[]>`? Just curious. In JSF, if I can remember correctly, there is a `var` property. Therefore, it should be possible there.

Comment: itemLabel and itemValue represent bean property names, so no, it's not possible. You should definitely used typed objects rather than Object arrays anayway.